# Health Insurance for National D Visa (Poland) under work category

Tags: working-visas, health-insurance, europe, poland

I have received a work permit for a position in Poland and will shortly be applying for a residence visa.

One of the requirements states that I must have health insurance for the duration of the stay. I will be covered by my employer insurance once my contract begins, but during that initial settling in period I will need to insure myself privately.

Axa seems to fit most of the criteria, but I don't really want to pay for 12 months of insurance. How many months coverage is enough to satisfy the requirements for the visa? Do I need to show any additional documents with my application in this circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have already called the Polish embassy in my local country (New Zealand) and confirmed that you only need private health insurance for the intermediary period between your arrival in the Schengen area and your starting work date.

So, you should supply with your visa application information relating to your work permit, your starting date at your new job, the intended arrival date into the schengen and the private health insurance with dates covering your arrival till start work date.